# contacts.find(fields,options) is executing only for the last element inside a for loop in ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have an contacts array, I iterate each element in this array and create an contacts object and then before saving into device contacts, I use contacts.find() to check if it already exists in device contacts. but since this complete process takes place inside for loop. contacts.find() is executed only for last element.

```
private(contacts:Contact)
{
//constructor
}

somefunc()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        let contact: Contact = this.contacts.create();
        contact.name = new ContactName(null, lastName, firstName, middleName);
        contact.photos = [new ContactField("base64", "dfdgsf/nbbbb/hv....", true)];
        contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField("454******", "mobile", true)];

        this.contacts.find(
         ["displayName", "phoneNumbers", "emails"],
         { multiple: true, filter: "Sam", hasPhoneNumber: false })
        .then((contactsArray) =>
        {
            //do something
            /*based on result we will decide whether to save as a new contact or modify the existing contact*/
        },(error) =>
        {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please go through https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/ to understand the problem

Comment: Can we use promise or async/await so that until and unless the execution of then in contacts.find() inside for loop is not over, we should not iterate the next item.